# How do I make a fully connected network (no isolates) in R using ergm?

Tags: r, networking, ergm

I am trying to simulate a network using ergm (specifics below) that has nodematch, but would like it not to have isolates. Specifically, I want it to be fully connected; I don't want to remove isolates, but rather create a network that doesn't have any to begin with.

I know that the ergm package has an *isolates *term that dictates the number of isolates that are in the network; however, I'm unsure of how to implement it. Adding 0 as the coefficient for the *isolates *term doesn't work, as I kind of expected.

```
N <- 100
nett <- network(N, directed=TRUE, density=0)
nett <- set_vertex_attribute(nett, "wearable", rep(c("Y","N"), times=c(N*0.21, N*0.79))) 
nt.sim <- simulate(nett ~ edges + nodematch("wearable") + isolates, coef=c(qlogis(0.05),qlogis(0.1), 0))
plot(nt.sim, vertex.col=nodeColors)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. The `isolates` coef has to be `- Inf` to prevent isolates. Setting it to 0 essentially has no effect (as if the term was absent). Here is your code edited with `set.seed` added and you can use name of the vertex attribute with `vertex.col` to have the nodes colored by that attribute:

```r
library(ergm)
set.seed(666)
N <- 100
nett <- network(N, directed=TRUE, density=0)
nett <- set.vertex.attribute(nett, "wearable", 
                             rep(c("Y","N"), times=c(N*0.21, N*0.79))) 
nt.sim <- simulate(
  nett ~ edges + nodematch("wearable") + isolates, 
  coef=c(qlogis(0.05),qlogis(0.1), - Inf)
)

plot(nt.sim, vertex.col="wearable")
```

[image]